# Wanted to get middle text from PSObject in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a PSObject which contains the following Values

```
AZREUS/MYVM-0.mydomain.com
AZREUS/MYVM-1.mydomain.com
```

I need only the VM name stored in a new PS-Object, how can I do that.

The list should return like below.

```
MYVM-0
MYVM-1
```

Comment: Can you show us the output from `Get-Member -InputObject $MyPSObject`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or using -match.  Do them one at a time.

```
'AZREUS/MYVM-0.mydomain.com' -match 'AZREUS/(.*).mydomain.com' > $null; $matches[1]

MYVM-0


'AZREUS/MYVM-1.mydomain.com' -match 'AZREUS/(.*).mydomain.com' > $null; $matches[1]

MYVM-1
```

Answer (score 1):

a simple way can be to use -replace operator:

```
$list = @('AZREUS/MYVM-0.mydomain.com','AZREUS/MYVM-1.mydomain.com')
$list -replace 'AZREUS/'-replace '\.mydomain\.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

[YannCha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63194442/11025476) is an efficient answer if your strings always begin with `AZREUS/` and end with `.mydomain.com`. You can use a single `-replace` to get the desired result.

```
$obj = 'AZREUS/MYVM-0.mydomain.com','AZREUS/MYVM-1.mydomain.com'
$obj -replace '^AZREUS/(.*)\.mydomain\.com$','$1'
```

`$1` represents capture group 1, which was created by the first parentheses grouping `()`. It contains `.*` contents. See [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/6DMGlA/1) for regex explanation.

---

Taking the same approach further dynamically, you can use pattern matching. This removes all beginning characters including the first `/`. Then removes the first `.` and all characters after it.

```
$obj -replace '^.*/(.*?)\..*$','$1'
```

See [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/PXV076/1) for regex explanation.

---

Note that if your object items are not strings, they will need to support being converted to strings or you will have to do that yourself before applying `-replace`.